# Change memory size of image according to screen.(Mobile, desktop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, mobile

I want to adjust memory size of image according to screen size. Because same image loaded in desktop and mobile but i want to reduce memory size of image in mobile screen. I am working in [www.winni.in](https://www.winni.in/cake-delivery-in-goa). In this page lots of images that's are load in desktop screen and mobile screen. And consuming same memory. For example i will show you one image of product.

***SCREEN SHOT***:
[image]

This image consume same Size(4.91kb) in desktop screen and mobile screen. I want to reduce this image size in mobile screen. If it is possible then please let me know. My main motive is responsive website should fast and smooth in mobile screen also. i am checking page size from http://mobitest.akamai.com  then showing page size is 534.34kb.

***SCREEN SHOT:***

[image]

If any one have any idea then please let me know.

Comment: 5kb is pretty tiny for an image, HTTP is gonna take up most of the time. But look into the HTML5 picture element

Comment: @Joseph Young. Yes, But in this page lots of images loading. I want to save maximum size of images. Because in mobile screen no need as the same size of desktop image size.

Comment: If you are concerned about file size of images—then why do you post unnecessary screen shots of dialogues and websites, where the only important information is "the image has a size of 4.9kB" and "the websites' size is 534kB" (whereas the latter is even irrelevant for this question). The pictures are useless for your question. So now you essentially blew the size of your question from maybe a single kilobyte to 236kB …

Comment: @Martin. Thnks. I will remove the screen shots. I attached the screen shots for the better understand.

Comment: you could try swapping the images to lower sizes using media queries at different viewports. you could also combine images into sprites. can't think of a specific solution though. pretty broad.

Comment: I agree with Joseph's view. 5KB is already a pretty small size. Reducing it further may severely affect the quality of an image. What you should be looking to do rather is to spot the images that are greater than, say, 50KB, create stripped down version of them and load them with the mobile site. It's also possible to generate smaller versions "on the fly" rather than doing that manually (eg., using imagemagick). Also, do check out YSlow: it's a great tool for website optimization.

Comment: with a resolution of 1440 x 2560, a "mobile" screen actually has a substantially larger resolution that the vast majority of desktops - so perhaps you want a better image for mobile?

Comment: size =/= quality - you can generally shrink images substantially without (visible) loss of quality.

Comment: @iamgame. I am agree with you but i will load thousand images on the one page. I will save 2 kb in mobile device then page size will decrease.